# Rails minitest syntax for get :index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I am reading the Hartl tutorial and I have a question about whether or not this is the right syntax. How does rails know what controller to look in? I have 10 controllers and I am writing a test for static pages controller. How does it know what get :home refers to and where? Does it look in the associated controller with the file name? Or does it look in routes?

Also, is assert_response a rack test or a rails test?

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get :help
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does it know what get :home refers to and where?

Rails does a lot of *magic*, some of this magic falls into the category of [convention over configuration](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/Getting_Started/Convention_Over_Configuration).

In this case, the fact that the name of this test's class is `StaticPagesControllerTest` tells the test suite that it is testing the `StaticPagesController`.

It is standard rails *convention* to name tests this way.  You could technically configure any test to look at any controller or action you want, but following this convention has many benefits (another discussion).

When you tell it to `get :home` it is using the `get` [http method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) on the controller action named `:home`.

> Also, is assert_response a rack test or a rails test?

It asking rails for the status code received.  In this case it is checking to see if the status code was `200`.

Additional info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/ResponseAssertions.html#method-i-assert_response